# Adding .Net Framework on Wix installer duplicates installer

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, installation, wix, wix3.5

I'm deploying a simple `.MSI` installer. But, as test, I wanted to put as a prerequisite `Microsoft .Net Framework 4.0`, so I wrote this on my `.wixproj`:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <BootstrapperFile Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
         <ProductName>.NET Framework 4.0</ProductName>
      </BootstrapperFile>
      <Bootstra pperFile Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.4.5">
         <ProductName>Windows Installer 4.5</ProductName>
      </BootstrapperFile>
  </ItemGroup>
```

And:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="InstallTest" ApplicationName="Face Phi Install Test" BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)" ComponentsLocation="Relative" CopyComponents="True" OutputPath="$(OutputPath)" Path="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\" />
</Target>
```

And on my `.wxs` project I wrote this:

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
```

This works fine, and I can put `.Net Framework 4.0` as a prerequisite and doesn't allow the installation to proceed. But when I generate my `SetupProject`, I can see two installers:

[image]

1. `InstallTest.msi` is the one I generate on my `.wxs` project. The second one, I don't know where it comes from. **How can I have only one installer and connect it to my prerequisites?**
2. **How can I auto-install .Net Framework, instead of cancelling the installation?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `setup.exe` is created by your `GenerateBootstrapper` build task and contains the logic to  install the packages you have selected by `BootstrapperFile` elements. However, this doesn't include your InstallTest.msi.

To do that you need to create a bootstrapper package, which is a directory structure containing the msi file and a couple of xml files. Look at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages` for examples. You can design one by hand and copy it into that Packages folder using build tasks. Microsoft's informal tool [Bootstrapper Manifest Generator](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/bmg/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1567) also helps when designing and copying packages and can be called from a build task.

Once you have a setup.exe that installs all of your packages, you might want to put all the files into a self-extracting archive such as WinRAR or WinZip. I use a very basic NSIS installer because it allows me to create a professional-looking, custom welcome screen.

### Alternative

Instead of the Visual Studio bootstrapper, upgrade to WiX 3.7 and use a **WiX Bootstrapper** project (aka Burn project). The downside is that scripts to install dependencies under its system are not yet widely available, though a script for .NET is in the documentation. [See the topic "How To: Install the .NET Framework Using Burn".] One of the many advantages of Burn is that it is also a self-extracting archive.